# Read/Write Performance: DiskLruCache vs File System

Tags: android

I am building a gallery app where the images will only be loaded from file system and not from internet, want to know if there's any performance difference in reading/writing to file system vs DiskLRUCache (JakeWharton). If so, Can I use "DiskLRUCache" for storage then, by changing the storage directory from cache to SD Card/Internal file system ? Thanks

Comment: Read/Write to the memory certainly has advance of to file system. You should use memory cache to avoid create and gc of bitmaps too often.

Comment: I do understand about memory cache, but i am asking about "DiskLRuCache" which is stored on disk itself. If I understood your answer correctly.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you read/write to a directory retrieved from `getExternalFilesDirs` (no STORAGE permission needed), then it's all the same. i'm currently using that method to obtain an available directory for use with DiskLRUCache. access is delayed and slows down my UI, so i also use in-memory cache as well.

the idea is to persist bitmaps to disk with DiskLRUCache, and store most recently accessed gallery items in LruCache.

fetch the object from the LruCache (memory cache), and if not found, read from disk (DiskLRUCache), then place in your in-memory cache object. creating a nice wrapper for this logic should make interfacing with it straight forward.